# why is using List without diamond operator as a method parameter type causing a compile error?

Tags: java, generics, resultset

I am retrieving a resultset from the database which comes in the form of a list of objects. I wrote a method that converts this list of objects to instances of class `LocalizedCropNameDTO`. Here is the method:

```
private List<LocalizedCropNameDTO> convertObjectArraysToLocalizedCropNameDTOs(List objectArrayList){
    return objectArrayList.stream().map(object -> {
        Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) object;
        return new LocalizedCropNameDTO((String) objectArray[0], (BigInteger) objectArray[1], (BigInteger) objectArray[2]);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will not compile. The error in intellij is: `Required type List<LocalizedCropNameDTO> Provided: Object`.

When i add the diamond operator `<?>` after `List` it does compile. I find this very strange because List should be interpreted the same as `List<?>` under the hood. But instead the compiler starts interpreting List as Object.

Can anyone explain why this is so? I'm very puzzled by this.

Thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) answer your question?

Comment: `<?>` isn't the diamond "operator". That's `<>`. `<?>` is paramterising with a wildcard. Anyway, it seems to be that when you have *rare types*, the Java language gives up trying to infer, so return type from `collect` is just its raw type. So, avoid raw and rare types.

Comment: Using a raw type makes all methods not inherited from a non-raw base class raw too. So `objectArrayList.stream().map(...)` has type `Stream`, not `Stream<Something>`, whatever the contents of `...`.